# Linked server query in profiler

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, profiler

I was profiling a DB for queries against it but have noticed that when a table in the DB is accessed through a linked server this does not show in profiler.  Can anyone advise on why this is or what events I need to select to ensure this is captured in future?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124379/profiling-linked-server

Comment: Thanks, from what I have read it seems what I am after is not possible which makes it difficult to find incoming queries.